# Is it possible to restore db from WALs twice?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, backup, wal

I have a main database server that WALs is periodically archived on s3. So s3 has a 'snapshot' of a database with all the corresponding latest WALs. 
I have another (local) database server that I want to periodically 
update to be actual to the state of the main database server.
 So I once copied "main" directory from s3 and applied all the WALs from s3 by using restore.conf
The only thing I've changed in this file is:

```
restore_command = 'aws s3 cp s3://%bucketName%/database/pg_wal/%f %p'
```

It was successful.
After some time I want to apply all the latest WALs from s3 to being "more synchronized" with a main database server. **Is it possible to do it somehow?** I know exactly, that I did not make any updates or writes into my "copied" database server. When I'm trying to do it in the *exactly same way as before* I am getting the next errors (from stderr):

```
fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject 
operation: Key "database/pg_wal/00000001000001EF0000001F" does not 
exist
fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject 
operation: Key "database/pg_wal/00000002.history" does not exist
fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject 
operation: Key "database/pg_wal/00000001.history" does not exist
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject 
operation: Forbidden
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject 
operation: Forbidden
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject 
operation: Forbidden
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject 
operation: Forbidden
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject 
operation: Forbidden
```

**This is a more detailed description of my procedure:**

I have a two directories on s3: `basebackup` and `pg_wal`. `basebackup` contains `base`, `global`, `pg_logical`, `pg_multixact`, `pg_xact`, `PG_VERSION`, `backup_label` files.

When I recover it the first time, I do the following:

1. Stop postgres
2. `aws s3 sync s3://%bucketname%/basebackup ~/10/main`
3. `mkdir` empty directories in `~/10/main`
4. copied `recovery.conf.sample` into `~/10/main/recovery.conf`
5. edit `recovery.conf` as above
6. start PostgreSQL

When I'm doing it again after some time I'm doing steps 1, 4, 5, 6 and getting the described result.

Probably, I need to somehow specify the first WAL from s3 bucket to being restored? Because we already restored some of them before. Or it is impossible at all?

Comment: Ok, so that means that after the first recovery, the backup came up as an independent database. Then you cannot continue recovering it. So there is some mystery about how you got it to try and recover again. Can you shed light on that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe. I mean, the difference between my database and an original database is just several WAL files, that I would like to recover from s3. Is it impossible to do it considering my database did not changed at all since the first recovery?

Comment: I see. The missing link is how you got the database to recover again (and fail) after stap 6). That shouldn't be possible, because `backup_label` and `recovery.conf` will be renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a lot wrong with your procedures:

- A complete backup does not only consist of the files and directories you list above, but of the *complete* data directory (`pg_wal`/`pg_xlog` can be empty).
- After the first recovery, PostgreSQL will choose a new time line, rename `backup_label` and `recovery.conf` and come up as a regular database.

  You cannot resume recovering such a database. I don't know what exactly you did to get into recovery mode again, but you must have broken something.

Once a database has finished recovery, the only way to recover further is to restore the initial backup again and recover from the beginning.

Have you considered using point-in-time recovery with `recovery_target_action = 'pause'`? Then PostgreSQL will stay in recovery mode, and you can run queries against the database. To continue recovering, define a new recovery target and restart the server.

Comment: Thank you! Now it gets clearer. My final question: When we use recovery_target_action, does postgres can somehow understand which WALs should be recovered in the following times? Let's say, before the first recovery, I had 50 WALs on my s3, that were successfully recovered. After some time, there are 100 more WALs (150 in total), and when the recovery starts, postgres should somehow understand then  we need to skip the first 50 WALs on s3 and apply only the 100 latest. Can this situation be handled with some of recovery_target_* ?

Comment: This happens automatically. PostgreSQL performs *restart points* (checkpoints in recovery mode), and recovery will resume from the latest restart point.

Comment: So, out of curiosity: what did you do to get PostgreSQL into recovery a second time?

Comment: Steps 4-6 from above. But it actually fails (that's what this topic about), and that's why I am here :).

Comment: Once recovery has finished the first time, there is no more `backup_label`, so PostgreSQL won't go into recovery again, so `restore_command` is not used, so you cannot get the error messages you report. That is what is confusing me. Did you somehow create a new `backup_label`?

Comment: Well, I don't have any backup_label. Actually, my restore_command looks like `restore_command = aws s3 cp s3://%bucketname/database/pg_wal/%f %p >> /var/lib/postgresql/recovery.log 2>> /var/lib/postgresql/recovery-error.log`. I did it once again, and that is the content of `recovery-error.log` : `fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden`
'. recovery.conf became recovery.done